# xtest and ytest details in randomForest () in R

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation

As I understand, RF has an internal in-the-bag and out-of-bag validation technique such that 1/3 of the data is withheld (out of bag) and 2/3 of the data is used to train the rf model.

My question is that if above is true, why is there a need to partition the dataset and consequently use the xtest & ytest parameters.

Please consider the question in terms of regression and not classification.

Comment: I have exactly the same question, its unfortunately not documented in the help.

Comment: I am also a little confused about this. My guess is that this is about cross-validation. Maybe this question could be redirected to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Anyone know if this question ever got answered? After literally days of Googling I was excited to finally see this as one of my search results. Alas!